# Merge and sort data from multiple tabs to a single "Master" tab in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Our company was using Google Sheets for the last several months and we had a system working great, but are now transitioning to Excel.

The tab in the Google Sheet where all the data is merged and sorted is called MASTER TEST and is found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MspVxTLWWrqr-ZEWhKU7q9knthg-n3D_cgGIz83cupo/edit#gid=178448142)

In Google Sheet we used formula:

```
=query({Data1, Data2, Data3},"Select Col1, ... where Col1 is not null order by Col1")
```

Data is merged: `{Data1, Data2, Data3}` is data from multiple tabs.

The result is merged and sorted data. How can I make the same report in Excel?

---

Basically, every call we receive is logged in a spreadsheet in a tab unique to each representative. We have a CURRENT WEEK tab which is supposed to hold a static version of all the calls received by every rep, sorted by date. In Sheets this was done with a `=query()` formula, but Excel does not seem to support such a thing.

I tried using `Data>From Other Sources>From Microsoft Query` but frankly this does not work since it only grabs the data from columns with data validation and gets very slow and breaks with too much data.

Comment: The question is unclear and too broad. What result do you want to achieve? What have you tried? Please, try to split the task into short and clear questions, so anyone could help you.

Comment: "The question is unclear and too broad" If you open the Google Sheet file I attached then it should be extremely clear.
"What result do you want to achieve" - "We have a CURRENT WEEK tab which is supposed to hold a static version of all the calls received by every rep, sorted by date."
"What have you tried" - " I tried using Data>From Other Sources>From Microsoft Query..."
Happy?  I'll editwhere needed to make something more clear, but downvoting and posting nothing but "this is unclear" when it's actually pretty clear if you spent any time to look at what was posted I won't entertain

Comment: As I understand, your task: you need to export your file into Excel. And when you do this, then formula on MASTER TEST `=query({arrayformula({...})},"Select Col1...",)` won't work. And you want Excel to do the same as formula does. Am I right?

Comment: I realize that the =query() formula doesn't exist in Excel so I have no pretensions that a simple export will work. I just need the same data view in Excel as =query() provides in Google Sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pivot Tables in Excel VS query in Google Sheet**

I suggest you using Pivot Tables, or Pivot Query in Excel. Here's some explanations:

- Pivot Tables in Excel can handle big data very fast, query in Google Sheets can't do this
- but query is more flexible and it refreshes simultaneously.

So if you are willing to work with data in excel, it may be harder to set your report. Sorting is easy task for Pivot Tables, but merging data from multiple tabs is not so easy.

---

**Merging data**

The goal in your case is to merge data from multiple tabs in excel. You can make it in two ways:

1. Use [VBA to collect data into single tab](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1184-excel-merge-multiple-worksheets-into-one.html).
2. Use Pivot Tables. [Here's tutorial on how](http://www.contextures.com/PowerPivot-Identical-Excel-Files.html) to accomplish this.

And still the best way for data manipulating is to use single tab for all your data.